# Proj R_A discrepancy with computed authalic radius

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

Using Pyproj, I attempted to create a spherical CRS using the authalic radius from WGS84:

```py
import pyproj

wgs84_spherical = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4('+proj=latlon +ellps=sphere +R_A=WGS84')

print(wgs84_spherical.ellipsoid.to_wkt(pretty=True))
print((
    wgs84_spherical.ellipsoid.semi_major_metre / 1000.0, 
    wgs84_spherical.ellipsoid.semi_minor_metre / 1000.0,
))
```

```
ELLIPSOID["Normal Sphere (r=6370997)",6370997,0,
    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
        ID["EPSG",9001]]]

(6370.997, 6370.997)
```

I was expecting the output to show a sphere of radius ~6371.0072 km, which is ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Authalic_radius)) the authalic radius of the earth.

When I calculate the authalic radius manually using WGS84 parameters, I get a similar quantity to the one reported on Wikipedia:

```py
from math import atanh, log, pi, sqrt

def ellipsoid_authalic_radius(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    a2 = a ** 2.0
    b2 = b ** 2.0
    e = sqrt((a2 - b2) / a2)
    return sqrt(
        (a2 * 0.5) +
        (b2 * 0.5) * (atanh(e) / e)
    )

wgs84 = pyproj.CRS('WGS84')
wgs84_authalic_radius = ellipsoid_authalic_radius(
    wgs84.ellipsoid.semi_major_metre,
    wgs84.ellipsoid.semi_minor_metre,
)

print(wgs84_authalic_radius / 1000.0)
```

```
6371.007180918474
```

Thus, I was surprised to see that the radius in Pyproj is reported as 6370.997 km.

What is the source of the discrepancy? Do I misunderstand the [`R_A` parameter](https://proj.org/usage/ellipsoids.html#cmdoption-arg-R_A)?

---

Edit: @user30184 helped me find the relevant code in the Proj sources:

```c
#define SIXTH .1666666666666666667 /* 1/6 */
#define RA4 .04722222222222222222 /* 17/360 */
#define RA6 .02215608465608465608 /* 67/3024 */
#define RV4 .06944444444444444444 /* 5/72 */
#define RV6 .04243827160493827160 /* 55/1296 */

    int /* initialize geographic shape parameters */
pj_ell_set(paralist *pl, double *a, double *es) {

  // ...

        if (pj_param(pl, "bR_A").i) { /* sphere--area of ellipsoid */
            *a *= 1. - *es * (SIXTH + *es * (RA4 + *es * RA6));
            *es = 0.;
        }

  // ...
```

- https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/proj_4_6_0/src/pj_ell_set.c#L7-L11
- https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/proj_4_6_0/src/pj_ell_set.c#L61-L63

And when I run the equivalent Python code, I get more or less the output I expect:

```py
P = pyproj.CRS(proj='lonlat', ellps='WGS84').get_geod()

SIXTH = .1666666666666666667
RA4 = .04722222222222222222
RA6 = .02215608465608465608
RV4 = .06944444444444444444
RV6 = .04243827160493827160

print(
    P.a * (1.0 - P.es * (SIXTH + P.es * (RA4 + P.es * RA6)))
)
```

```
6371007.181082429
```

So this is very possibly user error on my part!

Comment: Maybe you should write mail to proj-dev mailing list and ask there why there is that difference of 0.0102 meters.

Comment: Proj calculates the R_A with code that is here https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/src/ell_set.cpp. Could you point what is wrong?

Comment: I am usually inclined to assume that I am wrong, rather than a well-tested long-established library like this! I can look and try to understand what their code is doing.

Comment: Could it be that the coefficients after line 356 `/* series coefficients for calculating ellipsoid-equivalent spheres */` are not as accurate as sqrt and atanh in your formula?

Comment: I doubt it. Those are C `double`s, which I believe is the same as what Python uses. I'd also be really surprised if their formula had poor stability and roundoff properties. That said, I have no idea where these magic constants come from and I don't know how this formula was derived. I can ask on the mailing list and report back.

Comment: @user30184 I copied and pasted the formulas from the C code into a Python script, and I get 6371.007181082429, which is more like what I expected. Now I'm *really* confused!

Comment: I wonder what is this "normal sphere" 
in https://github.com/RohitPingale/PROJ/blob/master/docs/source/usage/Ellipsoid.rst#ellipsoid--transformation that has 6370997 hardcoded. Could it maybe be picked because of the way you used `wgs84_spherical = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4('+proj=latlon +ellps=sphere +R_A=WGS84')`?

Comment: Aha, I bet that's the problem. I clearly misunderstood what `+ellps=sphere` does! I guess is a case of user error after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) helpfully discovered, the problem had nothing to do with `+R_A`. The problem was that `+ellps=sphere` has a specific meaning that is different from what I thought it meant: it is a specific built-in ellipsoid definition, with a hard-coded radius of 6370997, which is exactly the "mystery radius" from the question.

Relevant docs: https://proj.org/usage/ellipsoids.html#built-in-ellipsoid-definitions

I still don't know how to correctly construct this WGS84-authalic-radius spherical CRS using Proj, but at least I have answered the question I posted.